# Can tools "actively" perform a task or do I have to write the following example in passive voice?

Tags: grammar

There are many kinds of metal cutting tools, any of which can be used to complete a specific task with efficiency. For example, double worm screws **can drill** holes of certain sizes; lathe tools **can turn** various cylindrical workpieces.

Comment: The thing that drills the hole is a person or a machine, not the screws themselves... So I'd say you should say "can be used to drill", but I'm not certain enough to make this an answer, as there are exceptions, like cars that sell themselves: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96467/can-vehicles-sell-themselves-shouldnt-it-be-passive-voice?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The subject can have several different semantic roles in a sentence.  When the subject is not human, it can be the tool used (implicitly by a human) to perform a task.  It is correct to say

> The drill made a hole.

and it means the same as

> A person made a hole with a drill.

Note that these are both active sentences.  The passive alternative would be

> A hole was made with a drill.

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96467/can-vehicles-sell-themselves-shouldnt-it-be-passive-voice?rq=1), it depends on the verb you're using.

So you need to find out if drill and turn [are labile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labile_verb#Labile_verbs_in_English). Based on the Wikipedia link, it seems like they would be, so it would be fine.